# How can I call a shell script from a Java program?

Tags: java, shell, exec

I use ubuntu 10.04 with eclipse. I created a shell script, exam.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Hello World"
```

with chmod 755 exam.sh

On the command line, I can execute `./exam.sh   // ok command showing me Hello World`

I want to call this exam.sh with java code, this is my java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;
String cmd[] = {"/bin/bash","cd","/home/erdi/Desktop", ".","/","exam.sh"};

try {
    p = r.exec(cmd);
    System.out.println("testing...");//ok
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

This doesn't function, where did I make a mistake?
Yes I know i can search by google but I didn't find an answer to my problem. It gives howTos and tutorials about this feature but I didn't find an answer.

Comment: The original post didn't have a newline between `#!/bin/bash` and `echo "Hello World"`.  Erci says the script worked from the command line, so I'm assuming that was just a formatting issue, and added the newline.

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
cmd[] = {"/bin/bash", "/home/ercan/Desktop/exam.sh"};
```

You can just invoke bash on the shell script directly.  To run a command string (like `cd`) you would need to use the `-c` switch.

If you need the working directory of the script to be your Desktop, you can use another overload of `Runtime.exec`:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, new String[0], new File("/home/ercan/Desktop"));
```

Alternatively, the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class makes executing processes a bit nicer.

Comment: Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd, new String[0], new File("/home/ercan/Desktop"));

Comment: @erci: yes?  Is there something about that line that isn't working?

Comment: The line with process proc.... Gives error " No suggation avaible" . İ think i need new Java code

Comment: @ercidi I think it's `Runtime.getRuntime()`